# Не закрывается мобильное меню ( Открывается, а чтобы закрыть, нужно только перезагружать страницу)

Tags: javascript, opencart, меню

Не закрывается мобильное меню ( Открывается, а чтобы закрыть, нужно только перезагружать страницу).

Сайт: http://1678413.zr241323.web.hosting-test.net

Код js:

```
// Menu hover before
$('.main-menu').on('mouseenter', function() {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 820) {
        $('.overlay').fadeIn(200);
        $('.menu').fadeIn(100, function() {});
        $('.main-menu-title').addClass('active');
    }
});

// Menu click open
$('.main-menu').on('click', function() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 820) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.overlay').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
    }
});

// Menu hover after remove
function func() {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 820) {
        if ($('.overlay').is(":hover")) {
            $('.overlay').css('display', 'none');
            $('.menu').css('display', 'none');
            $('.main-menu-title').removeClass('active');
        }
    }
}

// Menu hover
$('.overlay').on('mouseenter', function() {
    setTimeout(func, 50);
});
$('.header .menu > ul > li').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('active');
});
$('.header .menu > ul > li').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('active');
});

// Mobile child menu click open
$(".column>a").on('click', function() {
$('p').toggle(); 
    if (window.innerWidth < 820) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
            $(this).next().slideUp(300);
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(this).next().slideDown(300);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: менюшки бургеры под мобайл обычно снабжают логикой закрытия. У вас этого нет.

Answer (score 0):

У вас блок с классом overlay навис над всеми остальными и не дает возможность кликнуть или тапнуть.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]